# Set LastWriteTime in the Compact Framework

Tags: c#, file, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I need to change the `LastWriteTime` property in a smart device project (Windows Mobile 6 Professional), so I'm using the Compact Framework.

The `File` class has the support to get the last wirte time (`File.GetLastWriteTime`), but the method `File.SetLastWriteTime` is not supported.

I tried using `FileInfo` class, and its `LastWriteTime` property, but it is read only for the Compact Framework.

How can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the compact-framework a lot of functions are not supported. You'll have to p/invoke this windows API function.

[SetFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms886812.aspx)

Comment: To use SetFileTime I need the file handle, how can i gat this handle? Ps: the file exists.

Comment: I'd probably p/invoke CreateFile. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa914735.aspx

Comment: To clarify a few points: The prototype you need to PInvoke for the file handle is `CreateFileW`. For setting the file time, `SetFileTime`. Finally, you must close the file handle using `CloseHandle` otherwise the changes will be memory-resident only and vulnerable to being lost to a sudden power failure (as happens with embedded systems).

Answer (score 2):

Try this class (I am sorry that it is so long, but you nedd so much consts and pinvoke) with

```
        DateTime dtNow = new DateTime();
        dtNow = DateTime.Now;
        Win32Setfiletime.setLastWrite(@"\zdump.exe", dtNow);
```

Win32FileTimes:

```
    using System;

    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;

    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    namespace SetFileTime
    {
        class Win32Setfiletime
        {
            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            struct FILETIME
            {
                public uint DateTimeLow;
                public uint DateTimeHigh;
            }
            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            struct SYSTEMTIME
            {
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
                public short Year;
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
                public short Month;
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
                public short DayOfWeek;
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
                public short Day;
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
                public short Hour;
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
                public short Minute;
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
                public short Second;
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
                public short Milliseconds;

                public SYSTEMTIME(DateTime dt)
                {
                    dt = dt.ToUniversalTime();  // SetSystemTime expects the SYSTEMTIME in UTC
                    Year = (short)dt.Year;
                    Month = (short)dt.Month;
                    DayOfWeek = (short)dt.DayOfWeek;
                    Day = (short)dt.Day;
                    Hour = (short)dt.Hour;
                    Minute = (short)dt.Minute;
                    Second = (short)dt.Second;
                    Milliseconds = (short)dt.Millisecond;
                }
            }
            static DateTime getDateTime(SYSTEMTIME systemTime)
            {
                DateTime dt = new DateTime(systemTime.Year, systemTime.Month, systemTime.Day, systemTime.Hour, systemTime.Minute, systemTime.Second);
                return dt;
            }
            static SYSTEMTIME getSystemTime(DateTime dt)
            {
                SYSTEMTIME st = new SYSTEMTIME(dt);
                return st;
            }
            static FILETIME getFileTime(DateTime dt)
            {
                FILETIME ft = new FILETIME();
                SYSTEMTIME st = new SYSTEMTIME(dt);
                SystemTimeToFileTime(ref st, ref ft);
                return ft;
            }
            [DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint = "SystemTimeToFileTime", SetLastError = true)]
            static extern bool SystemTimeToFileTime(ref SYSTEMTIME lpSystemTime, ref FILETIME lpFileTime);

            [DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            static extern bool FileTimeToSystemTime([In] ref FILETIME lpFileTime,out SYSTEMTIME lpSystemTime);

            [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
            static extern bool FileTimeToLocalFileTime([In] ref FILETIME lpFileTime, out FILETIME lpLocalFileTime);

            [DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            static extern bool SetFileTime(IntPtr hFile, ref FILETIME lpCreationTime, ref FILETIME lpLastAccessTime, ref FILETIME lpLastWriteTime);
            [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
            static extern bool GetFileTime(IntPtr hFile, ref FILETIME lpCreationTime, ref FILETIME lpLastAccessTime, ref FILETIME lpLastWriteTime);
            [DllImport("coredll", SetLastError = true)]
            static extern IntPtr CreateFile(String lpFileName, EFileAccess dwDesiredAccess, EFileShare dwShareMode, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes, ECreationDisposition dwCreationDisposition, EFileAttributes dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);

            #region "constants"
            [Flags]
            enum EFileAccess : uint
            {
                //
                // Standart Section
                //

                AccessSystemSecurity = 0x1000000,   // AccessSystemAcl access type
                MaximumAllowed = 0x2000000,     // MaximumAllowed access type

                Delete = 0x10000,
                ReadControl = 0x20000,
                WriteDAC = 0x40000,
                WriteOwner = 0x80000,
                Synchronize = 0x100000,

                StandardRightsRequired = 0xF0000,
                StandardRightsRead = ReadControl,
                StandardRightsWrite = ReadControl,
                StandardRightsExecute = ReadControl,
                StandardRightsAll = 0x1F0000,
                SpecificRightsAll = 0xFFFF,

                FILE_READ_DATA = 0x0001,        // file & pipe
                FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY = 0x0001,       // directory
                FILE_WRITE_DATA = 0x0002,       // file & pipe
                FILE_ADD_FILE = 0x0002,         // directory
                FILE_APPEND_DATA = 0x0004,      // file
                FILE_ADD_SUBDIRECTORY = 0x0004,     // directory
                FILE_CREATE_PIPE_INSTANCE = 0x0004, // named pipe
                FILE_READ_EA = 0x0008,          // file & directory
                FILE_WRITE_EA = 0x0010,         // file & directory
                FILE_EXECUTE = 0x0020,          // file
                FILE_TRAVERSE = 0x0020,         // directory
                FILE_DELETE_CHILD = 0x0040,     // directory
                FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES = 0x0080,      // all
                FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES = 0x0100,     // all

                //
                // Generic Section
                //

                GenericRead = 0x80000000,
                GenericWrite = 0x40000000,
                GenericExecute = 0x20000000,
                GenericAll = 0x10000000,

                SPECIFIC_RIGHTS_ALL = 0x00FFFF,
                FILE_ALL_ACCESS =
                StandardRightsRequired |
                Synchronize |
                0x1FF,

                FILE_GENERIC_READ =
                StandardRightsRead |
                FILE_READ_DATA |
                FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES |
                FILE_READ_EA |
                Synchronize,

                FILE_GENERIC_WRITE =
                StandardRightsWrite |
                FILE_WRITE_DATA |
                FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES |
                FILE_WRITE_EA |
                FILE_APPEND_DATA |
                Synchronize,

                FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE =
                StandardRightsExecute |
                  FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES |
                  FILE_EXECUTE |
                  Synchronize
            }
            [Flags]
            public enum EFileShare : uint
            {
                /// <summary>
                ///
                /// </summary>
                None = 0x00000000,
                /// <summary>
                /// Enables subsequent open operations on an object to request read access.
                /// Otherwise, other processes cannot open the object if they request read access.
                /// If this flag is not specified, but the object has been opened for read access, the function fails.
                /// </summary>
                Read = 0x00000001,
                /// <summary>
                /// Enables subsequent open operations on an object to request write access.
                /// Otherwise, other processes cannot open the object if they request write access.
                /// If this flag is not specified, but the object has been opened for write access, the function fails.
                /// </summary>
                Write = 0x00000002,
                /// <summary>
                /// Enables subsequent open operations on an object to request delete access.
                /// Otherwise, other processes cannot open the object if they request delete access.
                /// If this flag is not specified, but the object has been opened for delete access, the function fails.
                /// </summary>
                Delete = 0x00000004
            }
            enum ECreationDisposition : uint
            {
                /// <summary>
                /// Creates a new file. The function fails if a specified file exists.
                /// </summary>
                New = 1,
                /// <summary>
                /// Creates a new file, always.
                /// If a file exists, the function overwrites the file, clears the existing attributes, combines the specified file attributes,
                /// and flags with FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE, but does not set the security descriptor that the SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES structure specifies.
                /// </summary>
                CreateAlways = 2,
                /// <summary>
                /// Opens a file. The function fails if the file does not exist.
                /// </summary>
                OpenExisting = 3,
                /// <summary>
                /// Opens a file, always.
                /// If a file does not exist, the function creates a file as if dwCreationDisposition is CREATE_NEW.
                /// </summary>
                OpenAlways = 4,
                /// <summary>
                /// Opens a file and truncates it so that its size is 0 (zero) bytes. The function fails if the file does not exist.
                /// The calling process must open the file with the GENERIC_WRITE access right.
                /// </summary>
                TruncateExisting = 5
            }
            [Flags]
            enum EFileAttributes : uint
            {
                Readonly = 0x00000001,
                Hidden = 0x00000002,
                System = 0x00000004,
                Directory = 0x00000010,
                Archive = 0x00000020,
                Device = 0x00000040,
                Normal = 0x00000080,
                Temporary = 0x00000100,
                SparseFile = 0x00000200,
                ReparsePoint = 0x00000400,
                Compressed = 0x00000800,
                Offline = 0x00001000,
                NotContentIndexed = 0x00002000,
                Encrypted = 0x00004000,
                Write_Through = 0x80000000,
                Overlapped = 0x40000000,
                NoBuffering = 0x20000000,
                RandomAccess = 0x10000000,
                SequentialScan = 0x08000000,
                DeleteOnClose = 0x04000000,
                BackupSemantics = 0x02000000,
                PosixSemantics = 0x01000000,
                OpenReparsePoint = 0x00200000,
                OpenNoRecall = 0x00100000,
                FirstPipeInstance = 0x00080000
            }
            #endregion

            public static DateTime getFileTime(string sFile)
            {
                DateTime dt = new DateTime();
                IntPtr hFile = CreateFile(sFile,EFileAccess.FILE_GENERIC_READ, EFileShare.Write, IntPtr.Zero,ECreationDisposition.OpenExisting, EFileAttributes.Normal, IntPtr.Zero);
                if (hFile != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    FILETIME ftCreation = new FILETIME();
                    FILETIME ftLastAccess=new FILETIME();
                    FILETIME ftLastWrite=new FILETIME();
                    if (GetFileTime(hFile, ref ftCreation, ref ftLastAccess, ref ftLastWrite))
                    {
                        SYSTEMTIME st=new SYSTEMTIME();
                        if (FileTimeToSystemTime(ref ftLastAccess, out st))
                            dt = getDateTime(st);
                    }
                }
                return dt;
            }
            public static bool setLastWrite(string sFile, DateTime dt)
            {
                bool bRet = false;
                IntPtr hFile = CreateFile(sFile,EFileAccess.FILE_GENERIC_READ, EFileShare.Write, IntPtr.Zero,ECreationDisposition.OpenExisting, EFileAttributes.Normal, IntPtr.Zero);
                if (hFile != null)
                {
                    FILETIME ftCreation = new FILETIME();
                    FILETIME ftLastAccess=new FILETIME();
                    FILETIME ftLastWrite=new FILETIME();
                    if (GetFileTime(hFile, ref ftCreation, ref ftLastAccess, ref ftLastWrite))
                    {
                        FILETIME ftNewLastWrite= new FILETIME();
                        ftNewLastWrite=getFileTime(dt);
                        SetFileTime(hFile, ref ftCreation, ref ftLastAccess, ref ftNewLastWrite);
                    }
                }
                return bRet;
            }
        }
    }
```